# Sql query to get the first 50 person near you

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have users with latitude and longitude.
I want to get the first 50 person based on my location.

for example

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetProfilesNearBy]
@UserID int, 
@UserLat float, 
@UserLong float

AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 50 * from Users .... 
END 
GO
```

where @UserID, @UserLat and @Userlong is the user who send the request
UserLat for example is 31.97542 and UserLong for example is 35.911285

how to get the nearest 50 ?

Comment: Which SQL Server Version?

Comment: I am not sure how `GEOMETRY` or `GEOGRAPHY` types perform for distance calcs, but if you want the formula: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm - after you understand that, come show us where you are stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or above you could use the geography data type to make it a lot easier:

Example:

```
DECLARE @user geography = 'POINT(31.97542 35.911285)'
SELECT TOP 50 FROM Users ORDER BY @user.STDistance(Position)
```

Comment: the Position is the other User's Point is that right ?

Comment: In your Users Table you should have a column [Position] of data type geography. If you don't have that at the moment but instead you have two columns (Lat and Long) you could add an indexed computed persisted column to transform the LAat/Long into a geomarty data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT top 50 * 
FROM TableName 
where ColumnName >= Position
```